# Same Select statement inside procedure returns all rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this select statement which I want to call from within a stored procedure in mysql. It calls it from a table where there are only three rows and three columns.

```
SELECT RefsArray FROM C where InstaId like 'whatever'
```

When I call it in it's own query window it will return only the one correct value.

But when I place it inside a stored procedure, no matter how complicated or simple, it will always return all three rows.

Here's are some screenshots:
Using the procedure:

[image]

The select statement:

[image]

This is quite maddening as I've tried almost everything:
Indexing, redoing the whole table, making the where clauses a bit smaller, using a temporary table then querying that in the procedure, making it sleep until the select statement is complete, changing the type to mediumtext, double, int.

It works fine for other tables and columns but it's just this one column, that I need, it wont work for.

I have a feeling that it's because the instaId it's looking for is too long but nowhere have I read that it effects queries in procedures. What can I do to fix this? I need this to work with these IDs!

FYI here is the whole table of C.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. I changed the column name from InstaID to something short like yID and now it works for some reason.

Is there any literature behind this???

**EDIT**

The kind gentlehuman below helped me figure out that it was because my param was the same as my column name. mysql is case insensitive.

Comment: There is no limit as far as I know, certainly not that low. The question then becomes, what did you define the parameter for the stored procedure as? I am guessing `[VAR]CHAR([<19])`.

Comment: Well since I found the solution I am using a standard varchar(255), realistically I should be using varchar(29) because the standard string in InstaID (now yID) should be 19 digits_10 digits. The varchar wasn't the limiting factor as I thought it was (which is why I only used 19 digits in the pictures). This whole thing was so weird, can you try it out on your end and let me know if you have the same issues?

Comment: You may want to post the stored proc's `CREATE`; you should not have had an issue with VARCHAR(255), so something else may be going wrong.

Comment: @Uueerdo You're right, it wasn't the varchar, it was the column name length.

Comment: Changing the column name should have had no effect on the results of the stored procedure.

Comment: @Uueerdo IKR, but that was the silver bullet today.

Comment: My guess is there was something off with the substring parsing that you fixed without making note of, as it could easily result query execution with a `WHERE ref LIKE '%%'` condition.

Comment: @Uueerdo I just tested it to make sure, only changing the column name. When it's 'InstaId' it doesn't work, when it's 'xID' or 'yID' it works perfectly.

Comment: Oh, doh! It is probably because your parameter name matches the field name! (if case is ignored) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html  `'A' like '%A%'` is always true.

Comment: @Uueerdo *facepalm* that must be it. I'm so used to things being case sensitive I totally didn't think that would've been the case at all. Thanks for helping me figure that out! :)